# How can i convert the online documentation to pdf for printing

Tags: converters

I want the print of the whole scikit documentation

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/user_guide.html

They dont have pdf version and .

I don't want to open 100s of separate pages  and then print.

is there any easy way of doing that. Any tool or onlinr site or something

Comment: You should try asking this question on Super User.

Comment: thank god , i saw the answer before it was deleted, yippy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the Sphinx documentation system in Python, so just get yourself hold of the source code from https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/doc, make sure you've got the Sphinx library installed, then ask it to make a PDF for you.